# Is policy supported on mule runtime 3.7.4?

Tags: mule

I have a mule runtime 3.7.4 installed on my computer, I am wonder if it's possible to set up policies on this mule instance?

**UPDATE**

I just find this link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli#api-mgr-policy-apply, has anyone tried this before? is it possible to set up policy to mule runtime using this CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy management capabilities are part of any API Gateway distribution. Since the unification with Mule runtime, you can found those capabilities also in any Mule runtime with version 3.8.0 or greater.

So, replying to your original question, Mule runtimes with version under 3.8.0 have no policy management capabilities no matter the tool used.